# Double overflow?

Tags: c++, overflow

I have always wondered what happens in case a `double` reaches it's max value, so I decided to write this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#define UINT64_SIZE 18446744073709551615
int main() {
    std::uint64_t i = UINT64_SIZE;
    double d1 = ((double)(i+1)) / UINT64_SIZE; 
    double d2 = (((double)(i)) / UINT64_SIZE)*16;
    double d3 = ((double)(i * 16)) / UINT64_SIZE;

    std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3; 
}
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
0 16 0
```

But this is my output:

```
0 16 1
```

What is going on here? Why are the values of `d3` and `d1` different?

EDIT:

I decided to change my code to this to see the result:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#define UINT64_SIZE 18446744073709551615
int main() {
    std::uint64_t i = UINT64_SIZE;
    double d1 = ((double)(i+1.0)) / UINT64_SIZE; //what? 
    double d2 = (((double)(i)) / UINT64_SIZE)*16;
    double d3 = ((double)(i * 16.0)) / UINT64_SIZE;

    std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3; 
}
```

The result I get now is this:

```
1 16 16
```

However, shouldn't `d1` and `d3` still be the same value?

Comment: in d1 and d3 you're looking at integer overflow, replace 1 with 1.0 and 16 with 16.0

Comment: Yes, I can undestand that. My question is why are the values of d1 and d3 different. Wouldn't they both overflow and return 0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`double` overflows by loosing precision, not by starting from 0 (as it works with unsigned integers)

**d1**

So, when you add 1.0 to very big value (18446744073709551615), you're not getting 0 in `double`, but something like 18446744073709551610 (note last 10 instead of 15) or 18446744073709551620 (note last 20 instead of 15), so - less significant digit(s) are rounded.

Now, you're dividing two almost identical values, result will be either 0.9(9)9 or 1.0(0)1, as soon as `double` cannot hold such small value - again it looses precision and rounds to 1.0.

**d3**

Almost the same, when you multiple huge value by 16 - you're getting rounded result (less significant digits are thrown away), by diving it - you're getting "almost" 16, which is rounded to 16.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't actually know this. I guess you learn new things every day!

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of loss of precision. Consider the following.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

#define UINT64_SIZE 18446744073709551615

int main() {
    std::uint64_t i = UINT64_SIZE;

    auto a = i;
    auto b = i * 16;
    auto c = (double)b;
    auto d = (uint64_t)c;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my system the output is as follow.

```
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551600
1.8446744073709552e+19
9223372036854775808
```

`double` simply doesn't have enough precision in this case.

Edit: There is also a rounding problem. When you preform the division with `UINT64_SIZE` the denumerator is promoted to double and you are left with a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0. The decimals are not rounded off. The actual value is very near 1.0 and is rounded up when pushed to `std::cout`.

In your question you ask "*what happens in case a double reaches it's max value*". Note that in the example you provided no `double` is ever near it's maximum value. Only it's precision is exceeded. When a `double`'s precision is exceeded, the excess precision is discarded.